# How to insert JSON object with html tags into Angular2?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, angular2-pipe

I need to render JSON object with some HTML tags,

Component looks like

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { BiblioService } from './biblio.service';

@Component({
selector: 'my-bibo',
templateUrl: 'biblio.component.html'
  })
  export class BiblioComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private _BiblioService: BiblioService) {
   this._BiblioService = _BiblioService
     }
    public index: any[] = [];
 ngOnInit() {
  this._BiblioService.getBiblio()
    .subscribe(index => this.index = index);
}
  }
```

Template looks like this:

```
 <h1 data-animate="fadeIn"> {{index["hero-region"]["hero-headline"] </h1>
```

and the output looks like

```
— Samuel Backett in <em>Proust</em>, 1930.
```

The whole JSON file looks like

```
[{
  "dc.rights": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "hero-region": {
    "hero-headline": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "hero-headline-sub": "— Samuel Backett in <em>Proust</em>, 1930."
  }
}]
```

What is the best/easiest solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to display `index['hero-region']['hero-headline-sub']`? I'm trying to understand what the data looks like and how you're trying to render it in the template. A component sample would be ideal if you can share one.

Comment: Still not following but trying to. There's a small error in your template, it's missing the closing brackets (`}}`). Are you trying to render a JSON object? Have you tried using the built-in `json` pipe? (e.g. `{{ index["hero-region"] | json }}`)

Comment: Look into DomSanitizer https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html